# Input "value" returns escaped

Tags: html, forms, input, escaping, cgi

The following HTML input:

```
<input type=checkbox name="_name" value="_value">
```

returns to the CGI script the pair `name` and `value`, with the `_value` string naked of its HTML escape sequences.

---

**Example:**

If `_value` is:

```
123 &amp; 456
```

the CGI script only receives:

```
123 & 456
```

while I need to receive the non-escaped string.

---

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Can't you just un-escape within the CGI script?

Comment: Yes. But should I always expect user agents to unescape `_value`? In other words, is this a standard behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&amp;` is a [html entity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_entity_reference), and is interpreted as `&` by browser.

In order to get "&amp;" you need to set value to:

```
123 &amp;amp; 456
```

Comment: Thank you. I have experimented this works with a few modern browsers, however, my concern is if this behaviour is specified by the HTML standard. I'm not 100% sure if every HTML-compliant user agent will escape the HTML string before sending it via a form.

Comment: @davide yes, its in html standard (at least in html 4) - http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/charset.html#h-5.3.2

Comment: This perfectly explains the question.